# Spark is Running mapPartitions Twice

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to run a spark job which perform some database operations and saves passed records in one table and the failed ones in another.

Here is the code for the same:

```java
log.info("Starting the spark job {}");

String sparkAppName = generateSparkAppName("reading-graph");
SparkConf sparkConf = getSparkConf(sparkAppName);
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();

LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 1);
final LongAccumulator accumulator = sparkSession.sparkContext().longAccumulator("Successful Processed Count");
LocalDate endDate = startDate.plusDays(90);

Dataset<Row> rows = sparkSession.table("db.graph_details")
    .select(new Column("yyyy_mm_dd"), new Column("timestamp"), new Column("email_id")))
    .filter("yyyy_mm_dd >= '" + startDate + "' AND yyyy_mm_dd < '" + endDate);

Dataset<Tuple2<Boolean, String>> tuple2Dataset = rows.mapPartitions(new GetPaymentsGraphFeatures(accumulator),
    Encoders.tuple(Encoders.BOOLEAN(), Encoders.STRING()));
tuple2Dataset.cache();

Dataset<Row> successfulRows = tuple2Dataset.filter((FilterFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, String>>) booleanRowTuple2 -> booleanRowTuple2._1).map(
    (MapFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, String>, Row>) booleanRowTuple2 -> mapToRow(booleanRowTuple2._2), RowEncoder.apply(getSchema()));

Dataset<Row> failedRows = tuple2Dataset.filter((FilterFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, String>>) booleanRowTuple2 -> !booleanRowTuple2._1).map(
    (MapFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, String>, Row>) booleanRowTuple2 -> mapToRow(booleanRowTuple2._2), RowEncoder.apply(getFailureSchema()));

successfulRows.write().mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("db.deepak_jan_result");
failedRows.write().mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("db.deepak_jan_result_failures");
tuple2Dataset.unpersist();
log.info("Completed the spark job");
```

The spark job is running the mapPartitions twice, once to get the `successfulRows` and once to get the `failedRows`. But ideally the mapPartitions should be run once right ?

How can I ensure that the map partitions runs only once ?

The stages of the jobs are :

[image]

The first saveAsTable saves the successful records and the second saveAsTable saves the failed records

[image]

Comment: How have you verified that your job is running `mapPartitions` twice? It seems that with your `cache` operation this should not happen.

Comment: Yes, from logs I found out that it was running again.

Comment: Do you think you can edit your question and add those logs then? They might contain necessary info to figure out what is going on.

Comment: The logs might not be useful as those are internal to the GetPaymentsGraphFeatures function

Comment: While I was processing successfulRows, it took 4 hours. Is it possible that the saveAsTable for successful Rows is taking too much time and it is not persisting the result for long ?

Comment: That should not be the case. Without more debugging info, there is not much we can do for you. Can you determine the stages of both `write` jobs and show screenshots of them in the Spark UI?

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the spark ui

Comment: I think it is retrying some of the failed partitions that's why the mapPartitions is called again